# Display multiple highest values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

At the moment to display the highest value in my query I am using:

```
ORDER BY Height DESC
) T
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

This displays the highest value, for example 10, But what if two entries are both of the same value 10.

How can I make it so it shows both of the joint highest values?

Comment: Use MAX and GROUP BY instead of Ordering ? (a little bit more code would help to understand the problem)

Comment: you mean something like `Select distinct height from FOO order by height desc limit 30`? (this would return 30 distinct higher values of height)

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are both different RDBMS. Though Oracle does own MySQL you should only use _one_ of these tags on a question, depending on the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 2):

use in Oracle, use the rank analytic

```
select a, b
  from (select a, b, rank() over (order by height desc) rnk
          from your_table)
 where rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a CTE

**Using a CTE**

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT MAX(Height) AS maxHeight
  FROM   YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable
       INNER JOIN q ON q.maxHeight = Yourtable.Height
```

**or a plain where clause with a subselect**

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  Height = (SELECT MAX(Height) FROM YourTable)
```

Personally, I prefer using a CTE as it doesn't clutter up the statement *(well, not true in this simple case but in practice, I often find it far more readable than subselects)*.

Answer (score 0):

This will do and it's every simple too,

```
Select height from table where height=(select max(height) from table)
```

Answer (score 0):

here you have without subqueries, it's more complicated but it was funny to created.

```
select ifnull(@d,@d:=actor_id),actor_id,if(@d>actor_id,1,0)as t 
from t1 having t=0 order by actor_id desc;
```

here is the example in my computer.

```
mysql> desc t1;
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field       | Type                 | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| actor_id    | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   |     | 0                   |       |
| first_name  | varchar(45)          | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| last_name   | varchar(45)          | NO   |     | NULL                |       |
| last_update | timestamp            | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * From t1 order by actor_id desc limit 5;
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
| actor_id | first_name | last_name | last_update         |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
|    20001 | test       | test      | 2012-12-13 09:12:50 |
|    20001 | test       | test      | 2012-12-13 09:12:51 |
|     2000 | b          | a         | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|     2000 | b          | a         | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
|     2000 | b          | a         | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |
+----------+------------+-----------+---------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>     select ifnull(@d,@d:=actor_id),actor_id,if(@d>actor_id,1,0)as t 
    ->     from t1 having t=0 order by actor_id desc;
+-------------------------+----------+---+
| ifnull(@d,@d:=actor_id) | actor_id | t |
+-------------------------+----------+---+
|                   20001 |    20001 | 0 |
|                   20001 |    20001 | 0 |
+-------------------------+----------+---+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```